# Scheduled publication not working in Umbraco

Tags: umbraco

I am using Umbraco 7.5.2, installed on a VM in Azure.

When a Publish At date is set, the page is never published. I have tried the following steps.

1. Create and publish a page
2. Unpublish the page
3. Set the Publish At date to a few minutes in the future and Save&Publish
4. Verified page is definitely not visible
5. Wait for the time to roll around, and even a few minutes more
6. Page is never published.

The following message appears in the logs on save when setting the publish at date, which is normal.  But no other messages appear after and the page is never published.

2016-10-25 17:46:20,784 [P4808/D10/T21] INFO Umbraco.Core.Services.ContentService - Content 'Video1' with Id '1312' is awaiting release and could not be published.

I've made a copy of my production Umbraco folder and of the database ON THE SAME VM. That instance works for scheduled publishing.

I'm wondering if anyone can provide some clues as to what the issue could be or where I could look.  I'd like to avoid having to migrate my production data to this test site.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Marcin's answer, also check that the server can access itself, as it pings itself to fire the scheduled publishing. If it can't resolve it's own address, the scheduled publish will fail. It doesn't happen often, but I've seen a few VERY locked down installs where the server can't resolve it's own address.

Comment: It's a hosting issue in this case, you have to get whoever looks after the site hosting to make sure the web server is able to ping itself.

Answer (score 3):

The problem may be related with different time-zone on azure VM as Umbraco is using server time to proceed inside the code execution. This should be the first thing to check.

In version **7.6.0** (https://our.umbraco.org/contribute/releases/760) it will be possible to set up server timezone and then set up a time with precise offset, so those type of problems shouldn't be seen then.

Comment: Both the dev and prod environments are on the same VM in Azure.  The Prod DB does not work with either Dev nor Prod code.  The Dev DB works with both Dev and Prod code. The timezones are identical for both dbs.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was a wrong `umbracoApplicationUrl` path (it has to point to ***YOURDOMAIN/umbraco***) After fixing this url everything started working fine